# Semen eating scene in Toni Erdmann

Tags: toni-erdmann

Somewhere in the middle of *Toni Erdmann* the main character (a lady) eats semen of her lover (the scene is disgusting, but it is not the point). And she does it not at the end of an intercourse but instead of one.

I am wondering what is the point of this scene. Is it an attempt to show how disturbed the lady is or does she just believe that a semen diet can improve her job performance and makes her a hot-shot consultant?

Answer (score 5):

I think it's to show her dominance.

There is a constant theme of authority and deference on the workplace ladder in the movie, and the artifice and shallowness of it. How unsatisfying it is.

By making him deposit his semen on a plate and eating it she demonstrates her power over him and belittles him.

Perhaps the directors goal was to make your headspin and keep you off guard, questioning who this woman is and what does she want.